# Is there anyway to decrypt data from database while showing it on a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, datagridview

```
string db = @" Data Source = Adeed\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = TMS; Integrated Security = True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db);
string dgquery;

// query check if start break null then calculate hours without breaks
dgquery = ("SELECT * FROM [HDMS].[DBO].[pnt_reg_info] WHERE reg_date BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and Active = '0' order by pnt_id");                         

SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(dgquery, con);

try
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;

    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dbdataset);

    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    sda.Update(dbdataset);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: perform the decrypt part on rowdatabound event, this event is called before displaying the data of each row

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection